# how to fix Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.JLabel cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: java

I have use TableCellRenderer to put in every cell of JTable a JLabel but when I want to get Value of selected cell and put in a query this problem is show.What to do.

at row=0 cloumn=0 is a JLabel and I want to get value of JLabel and put in query

Display((String) table.getValueAt(0, 0));

```
private void Display(String selectrow) {    
     try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:fiekdb","sys as sysdba","Albaniti111");
               String s="Select IdMenu,Ushqimi_pija,Qmimi,Lloji from Menu where IdMenu='"+selectrow+"'";

               PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(s);
               ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    int vlera4=rs.getInt("IdMenu");
                   String vlera=rs.getString("IdMenu");
                   String vlera1=rs.getString("Ushqimi_pija");
                   String vlera2=rs.getString("Qmimi");
                   String vlera3=rs.getString("Lloji");                    

                    obj[0]=vlera;
                    obj[1]=vlera1;
                    obj[2]=vlera2;
                    obj[3]=vlera3;

                    Select1(Select(vlera4));                    

                }
    } catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal code example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far ( Code snippet ).

Comment: I assume the problem is with `Display((String) table.getValueAt(0, 0));` rather than the code you've included?  What does `getValue` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the exception because you are trying to cast a `JLabel` to `String`.

> at row=0 cloumn=0 is a JLabel and I want to get value of JLabel and put in query
>
> ```
> Display((String) table.getValueAt(0, 0));
> ```

If you want the text-content of a label, use [JLabel.getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getText()) instead:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)table.getValueAt(0, 0);
String text = label.getText();
Display(text);
```

Side Note: According to the usual coding conventions for Java, method names should start with a lower case letter, therefore `Display()` should be renamed to `display()`.